# hibernate query : how to use a secondary join?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Not easy to explain.
A simple example :
An `employee` table, with many fields.
A `city` table, where an employee goes regurlarly.
A `speciality` table, in which an employee gets a good knowledge.

Two relation tables for that : `emp_city`  and `emp_spec`.

Java EmpCity class attributes : `int id, Employee-class emp, City-class city`.
Same for EmpSpec class : `int id, Employee-class emp, Spec-class spec`

Of course the class attributes are annotated `@ManyToOne`

I would like to fetch the List of EmpCity classes for employees who get the *computer* speciality and regurlarly in *London* :

`@NameQuery(name = "findEmpCountryByCityAndSpec", query = "SELECT ec FROM EmpCity LEFT JOIN FETCH ec.emp WHERE ec.city.name = 'London' AND ....")`  ?

So I can't see how to join with the EmpSpec table to select *computer*.

Thank you.

Comment: It is best if you could add the Entity classes or an ER diagram to better understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your model (posting the entity classes would help), but how about the following query:

```
SELECT ec 
FROM EmpCity 
JOIN FETCH ec.emp e
JOIN EmpSpec es ON es.emp = e
WHERE ec.city.name = 'London' 
AND es.spec.name = 'computer'
```